# Wordpress pagination sometimes doesn't load/show

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I tried to find soulution for this, but I can't find anything online and I can't figure it out by myself.

So, the problem is, that sometimes native pagination works, sometimes doesn't.
I tried to use different themes, deactivate the plugins, but problem stays the same.
I use `the_posts_pagination()` function with native WP loop, so there's no custom queries.

I would appreciate any advice you guys have. Thank you!

This is a screenshot of what happens:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom pagination using `paginate_links()` instead of `the_posts_pagination()`. Let the function is `wp103033_pagination()`
Then in your `functions.php` file add the function -

```
function wp103033_pagination($args = array(), $class = 'pagination') {
    if ($GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages <= 1) {
        return;
    }
    $args = wp_parse_args(
        $args,
        array(
            'mid_size' => 2,
            'prev_next' => TRUE,
            'prev_text' => __('PREV', 'text-domain'),
            'next_text' => __('NEXT>', 'text-domain'),
            'screen_reader_text' => __('Posts navigation', 'text-domain'),
            'type' => 'array',
            'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
        )
    );
    $links = paginate_links($args); ?>

    <nav aria-label="<?php echo $args['screen_reader_text']; ?>">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <?php foreach ($links as $key => $link) { ?>
                <li class="page-item <?php echo strpos($link, 'current') ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
                    <?php echo str_replace('page-numbers', 'page-link', $link); ?>
                </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </nav>
<?php }
```

Comment: Thank you, but problem stays the same. As I sad, problem is there with other themes as well. paginate_links() is for WP prior to 4.1 and the_posts_pagination() is for WP 4.1+.